# Currency xml feeds with lots of currencys

Tags: xml, currency

I am seeking an XML feed with currency data. It should be free and updated daily. I have Googled all day for this with no success. If somebody knows of one, please share info.

Comment: [This similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898650/are-there-any-free-foreign-exchangex-rate-web-services/898720#898720) may have what you want.

Answer (score 9):

The European Central Bank (ECB) has the most reliable free feed that I know of. It contains approx 28 currencies and is updated at least daily.

http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

For more formats and tools see the ECB reference page:
http://www.ecb.int/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html

Also, another feed I have found that contain more currencies:
http://themoneyconverter.com/USD/rss.xml
More information at: http://themoneyconverter.com/RSSFeeds.aspx

Comment: I'm looking for another free feed that has a few more currencies in it, including Iceland Krona. If anyone knows, please let us know.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your particular needs:

- If you just the top 28 currencies updated daily, go with ECB (very reliable).
- If you want up to 90 currencies updated daily, go with themoneyconverter (some down-time)
- If you want the top 16 currencies updated constantly, go to FXCM (also realiable).

Hope this helps.