# php function currency conversion

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with my PHP Script. It works fine if i convert less than 20 USD to INR but if i used it with more than 19 ($amount) then it shows only 1st digit of the resultant output. I want full resultant output to use this script. I am feeling glad if someone assist me to solve this problem.

Here's the code:

```
function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
    $amount = urlencode($amount);
    $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
    $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
    $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = explode('"', $rawdata);
    $data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
    $var = $data['0'];
    return round($var,3);
}

$from_Currency ="USD";
$to_Currency ="INR";
$amount ="20";

echo currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount);
```

Comment: you'd better use an official api to do such a thing, like Yahoo Finances API.

Comment: Use ECB XML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7125996/584490 BTW, this question is a duplicate of too many other questions.

Comment: Try this also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2461842/584490

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan i know that this is duplicate question and asked many time at stackoverflow, i try many times to find a suitable answer for my query and after it i open a new question here. And your given link is not suitable for my query. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your solution is not suitable to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$data = explode('"', $rawdata);
preg_match_all("/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\s?[kBM]?)/", $data[3], $match1);
$var = implode(",", $match1[0]);
$var = str_replace(",", "", $var);
return round($var, 3);
```

Comment: yeah, that's it! thank you @myron for such a nice help! It works, but what should i do to not show last 4 digit of output i.e, 20 USD to INR output is 1,077,00592 and we don't want to show 00592. The last values is not much necessary.

Comment: maybe you could try the edited code above instead. hope you find this answer helpful. cheers!

Comment: cool, everything seems to be fine! thanks once again @myron sir to make my web project a success.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code. This works as shown below the function...

```
function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
    $amount = urlencode($amount);
    $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
    $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
    $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = preg_replace("/((\"?[^\"]+\"?)[ ]*:[ ]*([^,\"]+|\"[^\"]*\")(,?))/i", '"\\2": \\3\\4', str_replace(array('{', '}'), array('',''), $rawdata));
    return json_decode( '{' . $data . '}' );
}

$from_Currency ="USD";
$to_Currency ="INR";
$amount ="20";

$amt = currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount);
//print_r($amt);

// The actual converted amount can be obtained with
$converted_amount = $amt->rhs;
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but your code doesn't execute, it show blank page.

Comment: ah, the preg_replace left off the enclosing ```{}``` so the json_decode didn't work. Fixed the function to return the decoded object.

Comment: I deleted all the crud and explanation...there is your working code.

Comment: thanks sir but it again show a blank page, don't got any output.

Comment: It works as shown [here](http://lou.pwnz.org/currency-converter.php?f=USD&t=INR&a=20). Nothing is being output in my example...add ```echo $converted_amount;``` at the end to output the amount

Answer (score 0):

That is because google seems to be returning a weird number in case of > 1000 rhs value. Print the whole response and you will see. The value returned is like 969 for $18, and 1á082.30965 for $20. I do not recognize that extra character in there, and no documentation is available.

Use a work around - convert 1 unit and then multiply with amount.

Comment: if it is possible for me to multiply every amount of my website then i definitely multiply the query amount manually.